# WP8 project creation fails in VS2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have VS2012 set up on Win7 32bit, WP8 and WP7.1 sdk set up, but whenever I try to create new project or add new WP8 project to existing solution i get this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/REAEM.png

I allso cannot use the feature described somewhere in webs to convert WP7 project to WP8 project, it just shots up as incompatible in solution explorer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvbrR.png

Could you please point me to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Windows 8 to use the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

```
Supported operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro

Operating system type:
Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
```

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471